# UIButtons Text Appearing Darker While Changing Tabs in TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I don't know why I am getting this problem.

Details - I have a tab-bar controller in my application. On one tab I have a form which contains some buttons. I am setting up the titles of these buttons. Now, when I change tabs and come back to the same tab, all the button titles appear darken.

I am attaching screen-shots as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you !!

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image]

EDIT : Here is the code of how I am creating the buttons -

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    float yFrame =310.0f;
            for(int i =0;i<7;i++){

                openPickerButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                openPickerButton.frame = CGRectMake(29.0, yFrame+10.0, 280.0, 48.0);
                openPickerButton.tag=i;
                openPickerButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                [openPickerButton setTitle:[formButtonTitle objectAtIndex:openPickerButton.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                openPickerButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
                [openPickerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                openPickerButton.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
                openPickerButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
                [openPickerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PickChoreButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [setPreferencesFormScrollView addSubview:openPickerButton];
                yFrame+=60.0f;
            }
}
```

Comment: I think they are drawn again and again every time you switch to other tab and come back,use break points to check what happens when you switch to other tab and come back .

Comment: Are you creating these button in viewWillAppear method ??

Comment: can we see some code of how you are creating the buttons?

Comment: @sparrowhawk Yes, i am creating these buttons in viewWillAppear method. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you should add them in the viewDidLoad Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in viewDidLoad your objects get called once.(As soon as the view get loaded.
Stop) 
In viewWillAppear they get called every time the view appears.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    float yFrame =310.0f;
            for(int i =0;i<7;i++){

                openPickerButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                openPickerButton.frame = CGRectMake(29.0, yFrame+10.0, 280.0, 48.0);
                openPickerButton.tag=i;
                openPickerButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                [openPickerButton setTitle:[formButtonTitle objectAtIndex:openPickerButton.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                openPickerButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
                [openPickerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                openPickerButton.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
                openPickerButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
                [openPickerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PickChoreButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [setPreferencesFormScrollView addSubview:openPickerButton];
                yFrame+=60.0f;
            }
}
```

Comment: I can not add it into viewDidLoad as I am doing some other logic there. I have to do it in viewWillAppear only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating buttons in viewWillAppear method create buttons in viewDidLoad method

Comment: cut the code from viewWillAppear and paste it in viewDidLoad ,this would fix your problem

Comment: I can not add it into viewDidLoad as I am doing some other logic there. I have to do it in viewWillAppear only.

Comment: @Aksh well you can create multiple methods, calling them in sequence one after the other, without using viewWillAppear